# Scrapy: how to fetch information that comes after some specific text?

Tags: python, regex, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to fetch apartment prices in my area. In the ad description, there is a list with attributes, like so:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Size: <strong class="description">100 m²</strong></li>
  <li class="item">Rooms: <strong class="description">3</strong></li>
  <li class="item">Parking space: <strong class="description">2</strong></li>
  <li class="item">Annual taxes: <strong class="description">$ 1000</strong></li>
</ul>
```

The problem I have is that some of these attributes, like annual taxes and parking space, do not appear in all ads. That means I can't simply use extract() with #-index  to fetch for that information, as I may capture information for the wrong category.

So my question is: how can I fetch information that comes right after the "Annual taxes" or "Parking space" text? Can XPath or RegEx do this?

Here is the code I'm using for the spider at the moment:

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'

    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css('li.item'):
            url = item.css('a.link::attr(href)').extract_first()
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        title = response.css('h1.ad-title::text').extract_first().strip()
        price = response.css('span.ad-price::text').extract_first()
        size = response.css('li.item strong.description::text').extract()[0].strip(' m²')
        rooms = response.css('li.item strong.description::text').extract()[1]
        parking = response.css('li.item strong.description::text').extract()[2] 
        taxes = response.css('li.item strong.description::text').extract()[3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

btw, I assume you missed to close the `strong` tag

```
response.xpath('//li[@class="item" and contains(.,"Annual taxes:")]/strong/text()')
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you mate! Also, I closed the <strong> tag.